# Mount problem on LVM partition

Tags: linux, mount, partition, lvm

I have a problem with mounting my lvm partition.

1. First I created file with a size of 7 GB

   ```
   sudo truncate -s 7G fooFile
   ```
2. Setting as a loop device. After this command I can see loop device via `lsblk` command (/dev/loop0)

   ```
   sudo losetup -Pf foofile
   ```
3. I set disk partition table via cfdisk

   ```
   sudo cfdisk /dev/loop0
   # I choose dos as a disk label and create new partition with a size of 5 GB
   # I can see loop0p1 (5 GB) partition via lsblk command
   ```
4. I created a physical volume from this loop device

   ```
   sudo pvcreate /dev/loop0p1
   ```
5. Then I created volume group via `vgcreate`

   ```
   sudo vgcreate fooVG /dev/loop0p1
   ```
6. I created logical volume via `lvcreate` with a size of 3 GB

   ```
   sudo lvcreate -L 3G -n fooLV fooVG
   ```
7. Activating volume group

   ```
   sudo vgchange -ay fooVG
   ```
8. Creating directory

   ```
   sudo mkdir -vp /mnt/myMountPoint
   ```
9. Last step :) mounting

   ```
   sudo mount /dev/fooVG/fooLV /mnt/myMountPoint
   # Two command have same error
   sudo mount /dev/mapper/fooVG-fooLV /mnt/myMountPoint

   mount: /mnt/myMountPoint/fooLV: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/fooVG-fooLV, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
   ```

How can i solve this error?

Comment: You forgot to make a filesystem on the logical volume.

Answer (score 1):

You have created a logical volume (LV) but you haven't yet created a filesystem on it. Here's an example to create an ext4 filesystem with a label `fooLV`

```
mkfs -t ext4 -L fooLV /dev/fooVG/fooLV
```